# Unable to add SiteEdit Script Extension in MMC

Tags: tridion

We are using Tridion 5.3. A new machine has been setup for Content Manager server as well as content delivery server(.NET).

When we try to add SiteEdit script extension in MMC snap in we are getting error 
"Object TCMSiteEdit.SiteEdit could not be created, please check the availablity".

Can anyone help us resolving this?

Comment: @Chris: can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can we assume you have actually installed SiteEdit? If so, which version? Typically running the installer will add the script extension to the MMC snap in automatically.

Comment: Now we installed SiteEdit 1.3 SP1, and we can see that SiteEdit script extension is already added in MMC snap in. Thanks for pointing out this. Now we are facing new issue when we try to preview page in Tridion GUI, it gives error "Type mismatch" for line sLeft = sLeft & SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation(objCP, sMoveLeftRail )

Comment: @user1453602 Since Chris' answer seems to have solved your initial problem, could you accept it please? It would help others with the same problem. You can always ask a new question.